# modify structure of node tree in python (application cherrytree)

Tags: python

I take notes with [cherrytree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/), an hierarchical note taking application written in python. A shortcut allows to insert date node, and the structure of date nodes in the tree is as follows:

```
├─ year
│  └─ month1
│  │  └─ day1
│  │  └─ day2
│  └─ month2
├─ year2
├─ a user node
```

I'd like to insert date nodes in a parent node named "journal" or whatever, as follows:

```
├─ journal
│  └─ year1
│  │  └─ month1
│  │  │  └─ day1
│  │  └─ month2
│  └─ year2
├─ a user node
```

The function **node_date** in **core.py** is:

```
    def node_date(self, *args):
    """Insert Date Node in Tree"""
    now_year = time.strftime("%Y").decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
    now_month =time.strftime("%B").decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
    now_day = time.strftime("%A %d %B %Y").decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
    #print now_year, now_month, now_day
    if self.curr_tree_iter:
        curr_depth = self.treestore.iter_depth(self.curr_tree_iter)
        if curr_depth == 0:
            if self.treestore[self.curr_tree_iter][1] == now_year:
                self.node_child_exist_or_create(self.curr_tree_iter, now_month)
                self.node_date()
                return
        else:
            if self.treestore[self.curr_tree_iter][1] == now_month\
            and self.treestore[self.treestore.iter_parent(self.curr_tree_iter)][1] == now_year:
                self.node_child_exist_or_create(self.curr_tree_iter, now_day)
                return
            if self.treestore[self.curr_tree_iter][1] == now_year:
                self.node_child_exist_or_create(self.curr_tree_iter, now_month)
                self.node_date()
                return
    self.node_child_exist_or_create(None, now_year)
    self.node_date()
```

Could someone help me to adapt it? I'm not a developer (my skills in python stop at modifying now_day date format in the way I prefer...), and I'd like to separate notes and journal nodes, without having to move manually the date node automatically created by shortcut. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I got help on a [project repo issue](https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree/issues/434). My node_date method is now:

```
def node_date(self, *args):
    """Insert Date Node in Tree"""
    top_node = "journal"
    now_year = time.strftime("%Y").decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
    now_month =time.strftime("%Y-%B").decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
    now_day = time.strftime("%A %d %B %Y").decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
    #print now_year, now_month, now_day
    self.node_child_exist_or_create(None, top_node)
    self.node_child_exist_or_create(self.curr_tree_iter, now_year)
    self.node_child_exist_or_create(self.curr_tree_iter, now_month)
    self.node_child_exist_or_create(self.curr_tree_iter, now_day)
```

As I said to the contributor, I don't understand why all thoses if/else in the project code while his solution is so simple, but for now it seems to work in the way I wanted.